# What is the best choice for $\mu$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A bottle is underfilled if it is less than $500$ml and overfilled if it is greater than $560$ml. Suppose the purchaser fines the supplier ${$}1$ per underfilled bottle. It costs the manufacturer ${$}2$ to clean up the mess of an overfilled bottle. What is the best choice for $\mu$.

$$\sigma^2 = 20^2$$

Let $X = \text{Cost of Fines}$

$$E[X] = 1[P(\text{underfilled})] + 2[P(\text{overfilled})]$$

$$=\phi(\frac{500-\mu}{20}) + 2[1-\phi(\frac{560-\mu}{20})]$$

$$\frac{d E[X]}{d \mu} = -\frac{1}{20} \phi(\frac{500-\mu}{20}) + \frac{2}{20}\phi(\frac{560-\mu}{20})$$

$$0 = -\frac{1}{20} \phi(\frac{500-\mu}{20}) + \frac{2}{20}\phi(\frac{560-\mu}{20})$$

Now the problem is trying to find $\mu$ here. I don't think the tables are going to help too much. I'm trying to use the c.d.f. but running into problems.

$$\phi(\frac{500-\mu}{20}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{500-\mu}{20}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy$$

But isn't this going to be a huge pain to integrate?

Comment: When I had to solve such problems, I was allowed to use the solver function on my calculator. Maybe you are allowed to use it too?

Comment: You have used the normal CDF as the derivative of the CDF... it should the PDF, i.e. no integral

Comment: But I never changed the cdf. Everything around it in terms of the expected value is different but $\phi(\frac{500-\mu}{20})$? Please just explain what you mean a bit more

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\phi '(\frac{500-\mu}{20})$. I didn't do this differentiation and to be honest I don't fully understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Slungpue pointed out in the comments, you seem to have conflated the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal $\Phi(x)$ with the probability density function $\phi(x)$.

So  $$E[\text{loss}]=\Phi\left(\frac{500-\mu}{20}\right) + 2\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{560-\mu}{20}\right)\right]$$ 
though you have the derivative correct

$$0 = -\frac{1}{20} \phi\left(\frac{500-\mu}{20}\right) + \frac{2}{20}\phi\left(\frac{560-\mu}{20}\right)$$

which translates (without an integral) to

$$e^{-\frac{(500-\mu)^2}{800}} =2 e^{-\frac{(560-\mu)^2}{800}}$$ and you can then solve this using logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the standard Normal CDF (call it $\mathcal N$ instead of $\phi$, the latter is usually the pdf)
$$
\mathcal N (a)  =P(X \leq a) = \int^a_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{x^2/2}dx
$$
then by usual calculus,
$$
\frac{d\mathcal N (a)}{da} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{a^2/2} = \phi(a)
$$
In your case you also use chain rule since $a$ will be a function of $\mu$